# can't login in phpmyadmin and mysql after fresh installation of lamp server and phpmyadmin on ubuntu 12.04 LTS

Tags: ubuntu, mysql, phpmyadmin

I am trying to search a solution for this problem, but didn't find a solution. I am getting an error while login in phpmyadmin

```
#1045 Cannot log in to the MySQL server

Connection for controluser as defined in your configuration failed.
```

I am trying to configure config-db.php and config.inc.php files reside in /etc/phpmyadmin/ directory. There i am changing $dbname and $dbpass in config-db.php as my root user and password but still can't login. After google, i get some clue and uncommented a line in config.inc.php:

```
/* Uncomment the following to enable logging in to passwordless accounts,
     * after taking note of the associated security risks. */
    $cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = TRUE;
```

These things are so ridiculous, follow articles like [Lamp server installation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ApacheMySQLPHP)
shows step by step things and i do the same thing, but i get this error thrice times. Even i can't login in mysql through shell.
Please help me to sort out this problem and know the actual reason why this happen when i am enter password twice time while installing mysql.

Comment: i am redirected from stackoverflow to ask this question on superuser

Comment: With what account are you trying to log in? Can you log in with your root account?

Comment: @Rhyuk: yes i am using my root account while setup during lamp server installation

Comment: Have you tried resetting your MySQL password?

Comment: i am using only root account on my server

Comment: @Rhyuk: Through this article http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/resetting-permissions.html#resetting-permissions-unix, i'll try but it is not worthy for me, not working on ubuntu 12.04

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing your MySQL password:

To reset your mysqld password just follow these instructions :

1. Start the mysql client process using this command

   `mysql -u root`
2. From the mysql prompt execute this command to be able to change any password

   `FLUSH PRIVILEGES;`
3. Then reset/update your password

   `SET PASSWORD FOR root@'localhost' = PASSWORD('password');`
4. Once have received a message indicating a successful query (one or more rows affected), flush privileges:

   `FLUSH PRIVILEGES;`
5. Then stop the mysqld process and relaunch it with the classical way:

   `sudo /etc/init.d/mysql stop`
   `sudo /etc/init.d/mysql start`

Source: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MysqlPasswordReset

**UPDATE:**

Lets try updating your current password. Do this:

```
$ pkill mysql
$ sudo mysqld --skip-grant-privileges
$ mysql
```

At this point you get the mysql command shell. You will need to update the root password and flush the table when you reset the password.

```
mysql> set UPDATE mysql.user SET Password=PASSWORD('YOUR_NEW_PASSWORD') WHERE User='root';
mysql> FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Now that you’ve flushed your passwords, just restart your mysql daemon.

```
$ sudo pkill mysqld
$ sudo /etc/init.d/mysqld start
$ mysql -u root -p
Enter Password: YOUR_NEW_PASSWORD
mysql>
```

Comment: I know the Source, but from shell i get the error after type mysql -u root: ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

Comment: now get this error after doing mysql -u root: ERROR 1040 (HY000): Too many connections

Comment: Updated the answer.

Comment: pkill mysql
sudo mysqld --skip-grant-privileges, after these steps, mysql command gives ERROR 1040 (HY000): Too many connections

Comment: If you are reaching the max connection limit go to /etc/my.cnf and under the [mysqld] section add max_connections = 500 and restart MySQL.Then try to update your password again.

Comment: On terminal , mysql running fine. But on phpmyadmin it shows same problem : Connection for controluser as defined in your configuration failed and #1040 Cannot log in to the MySQL server. As i  increase max connection and revoke all users who have super privileges but not equal to root@localhost

Comment: Cool, you can now login through terminal. Now you need to reset your myphpadmin password: http://en.kioskea.net/faq/673-phpmyadmin-access-denied-for-user-root-localhost

Answer (score 1):

Try password "mysql". Your mysql root and system login root passwords are not synchronized, you have to set each individually. Make sure you change the mysql root login!

Comment: i get this error ERROR 1040 (HY000): Too many connections after try password mysql and mine, but didnt work

Comment: Try resetting mysql with `service mysql restart`. Since default password didn't work, it sound like you'll have to skip-grant-privs as below.